# The expectation of absolute value of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I need some help with the following problem:

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from Normal$(0,1)$ population. Define $$Y_1=| {{1 \over n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}|, \ Y_2={1 \over n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|X_i|.$$ Calculate $E[Y_1]$ and $E[Y_2]$, and establish the inequality between them.

I may feel this should not be a very hard problem but I did get stuck somewhere. And I know it is $E[Y_1]\le E[Y_2]$ and I could prove this. But can anyone help me with how to exact find $E[Y_1]$ and $E[Y_2]$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Calculate $Y_1$ by noting $\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is also a normal random variable with known mean and variance.  Calculate $Y_2$ using $E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$.

Comment: This is exercise 5.12 from Casella and Berger's *Statistical Inference*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is worth knowing that the expected absolute value of a normal random variable with mean $\mu = 0$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ is $\sigma \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}$.  See Wikipedia on the [half-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution).

$Y_1$ is the  absolute value of a normal random variable with mean $0$ and standard deviation ${\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$ so $E[Y_1] = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi n}}$.

$Y_2$ is the average of $n$ absolute values of normal random variables with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$ so the average of random variables with expected value $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}$ meaning $E[Y_2] = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}$.

For $n \gt 1$ you have $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi n}} \lt \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi }}$.

Comment: can you explain how the standard deviation of $Y_{1}$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$? I thought since $Y_{1}$ is the sum of $n$ standard normal variables its variance will be $n$ and its standard deviation $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: @xabush $\sum_1^n X_i$ has a  normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $n$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{n}$.  So $\frac1n\sum_1^n X_i$ has a  normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\frac1n$ and standard deviation $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$.  Here $Y_1$ is the absolute value of $\frac1n\sum_1^n X_i$

Comment: Oh, you're right! I forgot about the outer $\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the general form of the mean of the absolute value of a Normal$(\mu,\sigma^2)$:

Following @Henry's link to Wikipedia's article on the half-normal, I found that there is now a page for the so-called "[Folded normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution)", which is an extension of the half-normal for $\mu\neq 0$. They give the expression for the mean, which coincides with the one given by @Henry for $\mu=0$

$$
\sigma \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}} + \mu \left(1 - 2\Phi\left(\frac{-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \right)
$$