# Expected Value With Signum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, random-variables, signal-processing, expectation

So I am trying to show convergence of a filter, and in order for it to converge, I need the following condition to hold:

$ E\{ \mathbf{s}  x  sgn(\mathbf{h}^{T} \mathbf{s}  x) \} \; \alpha  \; E \{ \mathbf{s}  x \}$

Where $\alpha$ is meant as 'proportional to up to a constant' and $\mathbf{s}$ and $\mathbf{h}$ are vectors of dimension Nx1 and x is a scalar. Now, we assume that:

$x \sim N(\mu, \sigma_{x}) \quad  \mathbf{s} \sim N(\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\sigma_{s}})$

Where $x$ and $\mathbf{s}$ are independent and $\mathbf{h}$ is assumed to be deterministic. Now I understand that:

$E \{ sgn(x)  x \} = c \mu$

For some constant c. (I think $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ but its just a constant so I don't care too much really). So then what would be:

$E \{ sgn(\mathbf{s}  x)  \mathbf{s} \} = \; ??$

And:

$E \{ sgn(\mathbf{h}^{T} \mathbf{s})  \mathbf{s} \} = \; ??$

Also, perhaps more generally with regards to my actual question, what assumptions to I have to make in order for that first condition to hold? Remember, constants can be multiplied out in front.

Thanks!

Comment: $E \{ sgn(x) x \} \ne c \mu$ for example, take $\mu = 0$. Regarding notation, I would only use dot if it's an actual dot product; otherwise too confusing. Likewise, your original inequality (?) can't be right because you can set $\mu_x = 0$ and the LHS is positive for large $\mu_{\bf s}$.

Comment: Fixed. So, if $\mu=0$ then is $E\{sgn(x)x\}>0$? Well, what is it in general then? Apparently I am quite confused here.

Comment: $sgn(x) x = |x|$ for scalars, so for a $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ r.v., $E[sgn(X) X]=E[|X|]$ is the mean of the corresponding [folded normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555831/the-expectation-of-absolute-value-of-random-variables

I'm just an idiot. So, what about those ?? equalities though?

Comment: PA60TA: Can you explain what you mean by my original inequality can't be true?