# Expected value of absolute value of sum

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

Is there any chance to tackle something like

$$
\mathbb{E}\left( \left| \sum_{i=1}^N X^{p_i} Y^{q_i} \right| \right)
$$

where $X$ and $Y$ are standard Gaussian variables?

Note that I am explicitely adding the powers and two random variables (I would love to be able to bring the $\mathbb{E}$ somehow inside the sum). Without it, the solution seems simple: [The expectation of absolute value of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555831/the-expectation-of-absolute-value-of-random-variables?rq=1)

I am also aware that I could apply the triangle inequality to get an upper bound. However, this is too unprecise for me.

Comment: Do you assume $X$ and $Y$ independent? Also, note that when all $p_i,q_i$ are even integers, the absolute values do not matter and your problem reduces to finding $\mathbb{E}[X^p]$ for which formulas exist.

Comment: Yes $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Unfortunately $p_i$ and $q_i$ are even AND odd (but positive integers)

Comment: @Raskolnikov Why can we disregard the absolute value when $p_i$ and $q_i$ are integers?

Comment: @sonicboom: I said EVEN integers.